# Hide Button using Jquery Dialog

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I use jQuery Dialog on ASP.NET C#. When I click button "Show dialog", the dialog is appeared and button "Show dialog" also display on dialog.
I want to hide this button. Please help me.
This is my code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(".printt").live("click", function () {
            $("#dialog").dialog({
                title: "Password Confirm",
                buttons: {
                    Ok: function () {
                        $("[id*=btnWhatch]").click();
                    },
                    Close: function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                },
            });
         return false;
   });
</script>
```

And ASPx

```
<div id="dialog">
    <dx:ASPxButton ID="ShowDialog" CssClass="printt" runat="server" Text="Show Dialog">
    </dx:ASPxButton>      
</div>
```

Thank for your help !

Comment: Just add $("#ShowDialog").css("display","none"); in the click event

Answer (score 1):

Just hide the button after the `Show dialog` button is clicked.

```
$('#ShowDialog').hide();
```

Comment: Thanks you. That's very simple.